# WebSockets with PHP and JS URL Problems

Tags: javascript, php, web, websocket, server

I'm just now trying to figure out WebSockets. I have a server setup with Ratchet in PHP. I run the server from the command line, and can connect to it just fine using "telnet localhost 8181" from a couple other terminal windows, and they can talk to each other. Here is what that code looks like (real simple):

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(),
    8181
);
$server->run();
```

So, next, I go to try it with a website, using this code:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8181
);
$server->run();
```

and for Javascript:

```
var url = 'wss://' + location.hostname + ':8181';
var ws = new WebSocket(url);
ws.onload...
ws.onmessage...
```

But, no way that I structure the URL, it always either instantly gives me an error, something like: "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200" or 500 or 404. I also tried this PHP code:

```
$app = new Ratchet\App('mywebsiteurl.com', 8181);
$app->route('/chat', new Chat);
$app->route('/echo', new Ratchet\Server\EchoServer, array('*'));
$app->run();
```

And still nothing. I used my actual website URL and tried every combination of /echo and /chat in JS, but nothing would work. It should be noted that I am trying to do this on a website hosted by Bluehost. If it is just straight up not possible with a hosting company, do tell, but I feel like it is, because I have SSH access and can execute the server php file indefinitely, plus it works fine when just doing it in PHP and connecting from other terminal windows.

I was going through this tutorial: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before but with Apache-PHP configuration. The solution was to generate an IPC file which would listen to WebSocket requests and an Apache module was responsible to handle them. Whenever the server started this IPC file had to be generated. I am not sure this is your issue. If it is not, then please tell me to remove my answer, however, the fact that you have trouble with WebSocket handshake means that on the server you are missing something, maybe a standalone application which will handle WebSocket requests.